# SimpleDateFormat get only the time

Tags: android, timestamp, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a problem when I try to get only the time from a Timestamp.

An example of the Timestamp is:

2012-04-19T23:05:00+0200

I think the format is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" right?
And it must be "HH:mm".

I use the following code, but it returnes nothing:

```
public String getTime(String Vertrektijd){
        final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        Date dateObj;
        String newDateStr = null;
        try
        {
            dateObj = df.parse(Vertrektijd);
            SimpleDateFormat fd = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            newDateStr = fd.format(dateObj);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newDateStr;
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct...

In the example time what you have given in the question(ie, "2012-04-19T23:05:00+0200") is missing MilliSeconds

Try passing this

```
getTime("2012-04-19T23:05:00.235+0200");
```

It should work.

Edit: 
As [MH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029225/mh) mentioned, If you dont want to use milliseconds
you can change the code to

```
final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

Comment: @Jelmer Visser: Or alternatively, change the formatter to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` to use the example you gave. Note how the last part is different, as, indeed, you mixed up the *milliseconds* part.

Answer (score 0):

Date has a getHours() and getMinutes() function, but it is deprecated. The proper way would be  to use a Calendar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime( dateObj );
int hours = calendar.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );
int minutes = calendar.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Dates_and_times) is an attempt to summarize all the confusing classes that Java and Android provide to do with dates, times and timezones. Basically, you do most of your date/time manipulations using GregorianCalendar objects, probably using methods from the Calendar superclass. To do locale-specific formatting, you need a DateFormat. But that can only format Date objects, so you need to convert your Calendar/GregorianCalendar to one of those first. Basically, SimpleDateFormat is for doing custom formatting, as you’ve already discovered.

Note there are two different classes called “DateFormat”.